# "Expecting ',' delimiter". Everything I've tried is not working

Tags: python, json

My Code:

```
    with open('music_queue.json', 'r') as f:
         data = f.read()

    list_str = data.split('\n')

    print(list_str)

    db = []

    for d in list_str:
        db.append(json.loads(d))
```

My raw JSON:

```
{"guild_id" : 00000, "song_list" : []}
```

I have tried doing:

```
data = data.replace('\"', '\\\"')
```

only for me to have this error:

```
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I've been at this for hours. What's going on?

Also, apologies if this has already been answered. I literally couldn't find anything here that I haven't tried already.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but have you tried to use just one 0 instead of multiple in your `guild_id` property?

Comment: Using one '0' works, but obviously ids are bigger numbers, would that cause a problem?

Comment: "I have tried doing" Why? What error did you get *without* doing that? More importantly, *what do you think each error means*? "I've been at this for hours" - aside from making one one-line change to the code, and reading some error messages - the rest was just trying to look for information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text inside *json* files must follow JSON standard and 00000 (without quotes to be marked as string) is not a valid value - replace it with `0` or `"00000"`.

When you open a valid *json* file you can load the contents straight into a dictionary, like this:

```
with open('music_queue.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Example of valid json file:

```
{"guild_id" : 10000, "song_list" : []}
```

P.S. You have to use double quotes `""` inside *json* files instead of single quotes `''`

Answer (score 0):

```
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes
```

Let's understand this error, it simply says the property name has to be in double quotes. Now this refers to your JSON file since 00000 is not valid. If it was a number 0 would have been enough. But having 4 zeros is making it read it as a string

Strings in json need to be enclosed in double quotes

Change the json to:

```
{"guild_id" : "00000", "song_list" : []}
```

Hope it helps!